# Hard olympiad geometry problem to prove ratio

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Let $D$ be a point inside an acute triangle $ABC$ such that $\angle ADC = \angle A +\angle B$, $\angle BDA = \angle B + \angle C$ and $\angle CDB = \angle C + \angle A$. Prove that $\frac{AB \cdot CD}{AD} = \frac{AC \cdot  CB} {AB}$.
Can somebody help me to prove it synthetically

My approach- let tanget from $B C ,  A B, A C$ meet at $X, Y, Z$ resp that gives $\angle BDC = \angle ACX$ and so on. Now extend $AD$ to meet $CX$ at $J$ we get $BDJC$ is cyclic (same can be done at other sides too); at this point I tried using power of point but it didn't help... Plz provide some help

Comment: Dear Ken. I have a proof. Notwithstanding, MSE demands a certain quality, and to achieve it, a post has to inform about the context (where have you found the problem?), about the progress you have made, your approach (where did it fail? where are you stuck?), etc. Once you've added this information, I'll be glad to answer your question :)

Comment: Also, I have noticed that you have made 8 questions since you are here, and haven't accepted any of them. Did the answers help? If not, why? Of course, you don't have to accept or upvote them (especially if no answer is satisfactory), but upvoting and accepting answers is a great method to reward users and show they helped you; it is sometimes frustrating to spend about an hour, or more, working on a problem — this is not that bad — and typing the solution — this might be —, and then get no answer from the user that posted the question...

Comment: Sir in my knowledge I have upvoted every solution and comment on my questions also I indeed understand that people have come here and given their time to it so best way to respect them is by upvoting.. Also thanks for giving your time sit

Comment: I meant accepting it (the green tick/check on the left of every answer) . As I said, it is of course not mandatory, but it's nice ;)

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't know about that

Comment: Oh, no problem :) That happens quite often. And thanks, btw!

Comment: I should be the one thanking you

Comment: I agree with everything @Dr.Mathva said but I would also add that while you do not have to wait endlessly, you should not be in a hurry to accept an answer the moment you receive it. In a subject like geometry, there is always a different solution (better or not, left to OP to decide). So I would rather wait at least a few hours or a day before I accept an answer, because once you accept an answer, it is less likely to receive more answers. More answers, more everyone seeing the question later learns from it. Upvoting can always be instant if the answer is correct :)

Comment: Thank you sir!!

Comment: @MathLover Couldn’t agree more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the shortcuts $\angle A=\alpha, \angle B=\beta, \angle C=\gamma$. Let also $\angle BAD=\varphi$. It follows easily from angle-chasing that $$\angle DBA=\alpha-\varphi,\; \angle CBD=\beta-(\alpha-\varphi),\; \angle DCB=\alpha-\varphi,\; \angle ACD=\gamma-(\alpha-\varphi),\; \angle DAC=\alpha-\varphi$$ This will be helpful due to the Sine Law, since want to prove a length-ratio relationship: $$\frac{AB \cdot CD}{AD} = \frac{AC \cdot  CB} {AB}\iff \frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{AC}{CD}\cdot \frac{CB}{AB}\label{1}\tag{1}$$ The Law of Sines considered in $\triangle ABD, \triangle ADC$ and $\triangle ABC$ respectively yields that (\ref{1}) is equivalent to $$\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha-\varphi)}=\frac{\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha-\varphi)}\cdot \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\gamma)}$$ Which is trivial.

Comment: Sir is there a purely synthetic method?

Comment: I would say no — this rather depends on what you mean with *synthetic* —. The problem is that you're not asked to prove some angle-property, some tangency, collinearity, concurrence, etc. which can all usually be proven synthetically. You have to show that a given equation is right; so, at some point, you'll have to jump from geometry to algebra, and that's where synthetic proofs end.

Comment: Of course, what I did with the Law of Sines can be done synthetically (that's the way you prove it); but that would make the proof too convoluted, I feel